# What are the differences between M.Sc, M.Tech and M.Eng.?

Tags: masters

Based on [this other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10117/is-it-possible-to-get-admitted-to-a-m-sc-degree-in-the-u-s-if-you-already-hold) where the OP asks whether or not a second Masters degree is possible, I realized that I am not sure what the difference is between *Master of Science* and *Master of Technology*.

I have graduated from a Swedish university and after 5 years of studies (Bologna process) I got my undergrad (*kandidat*) and masters (*examen*) together as it is very common here. I double checked my diploma now and even though I have graduated from the technical faculty and an engineering program, I am given a *Master of Science*. I believe there is no *Master of Technology* degree in Sweden, so I am not sure what it means. To make the matters worse, I stumbled upon another similar degree, *Master of Engineering*.

I would really appreciate some insight into the differences of these degrees, and whether or not they would be considered interchangeable abroad (read: outside Europe).

Comment: I believe it's all down to the school.  To further confuse you, I have a "Master of Engineering Science". :-)

Comment: Degrees with the _same_ name aren't always interchangeable!  (And my department offers both "Master of Science" and "Master of Computer Science" degrees.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some differences, especially in the concept of the programs M.Eng./M.Tech. and M.Sc (and M.A. obviously too).

From my experience, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Engineering) states this also, the M.Eng./M.Tech. degrees are rather given by Universities of Applied Sciences (at least in Germany, Canada, Finland etc,) and seldomly by Universities focusing on research. Any program that is research oriented will thus very likely give M.Sc. degrees.
The M.Eng. is even given as an undergraduate Master in the UK (see the Wikipedia Link) that gets granted immediately (without a bachelors in between).

For the career of a graduate, the title itself is not too important as aeismail mentioned, since any employer will have a look at what's inside (= the student track record).

Because there are so many slightly different programs, especially in computer/information engineering/technology/sciences I am not sure where universities draw the line regarding the "not granting a 2nd masters degree in the same field/area/discipline" policy.

Comment: M.Eng in the UK is 4 years, a M.Sc is 1 year, but you must do a 3 year bachelor degree first.   People can drop out of a M.Eng after 3 years and get given a bachelor degree.

Answer (score 2):

At some schools, there may be differences in the formal degree requirements, such as the requirement of coursework or completion of a thesis; at others, including the graduate school I attended, the distinction is purely a departmental issue—engineering departments give out M.S. or M.Eng. degrees, while science departments give out only M.S. degrees. I think, from an admissions perspective, in most cases, these would be viewed as largely interchangeable. Some schools may have very particular entrance requirements, but these would be noted as part of the admissions instructions.

Where I now work, we don't specify the nature of the master's degree required for enrollment as a PhD student; any relevant master's degree will suffice, and the exact title of the degree is more or less immaterial. (We do have to petition if it's a foreign degree, but this is mostly a *pro forma* process.)